Как примонтировать Microsoft Storage Spaces?
перешел я с винды на линукс, все ок но вот незадача. мой второй диск (nvme) не могу никак заставить прочитать его, fdisk дает эту инфу:
Disk model: Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 1TB   
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт
Тип метки диска: gpt
Идентификатор диска: FEAEA99B-0C48-11EE-92AD-782BCBB274D2

Устр-во        начало      Конец    Секторы Размер Тип
/dev/nvme0n1p1   2048     264191     262144   128M Зарезервированный раздел Micr
/dev/nvme0n1p2 264192 1953523711 1953259520 931,4G Microsoft Storage Spaces

однако я не могу монтировать этот диск, пишет ошибку. спрашивал у нейронки. Та ответила что проблема скорее всего с Microsoft Storage Spaces, Винды уже нет. Что делать?. Там ценные данные лежат.

как я помню, проблема в кодировке диска, там стоит gpt?

да, gpt, все верно

вроде-бы проблема именно в том, что стоит  gpt, попробйуте поставить тот, что на вашем диске с линуксом НО ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО СДЕЛАЙТЕ БЭКАП, Я НЕ УВЕРЕН В СВОИХ СЛОВАХ!!!

а ещё, сама винда очень плохо реагирует на сам линукс, просто перебросьте файлы на флешку, вы ведь можете в убунте открыть каталог с файлами, и перебросить на флешку, я так перекинул все нужные мне книги и форматировал диск поменяв кодировку

я не очень опытен с линуксом пока-что, можете ли вы обьяснить как это сделать или связатся для помощи?

я сам очень давно использовал убунту, я не помню как я делал, однако, в моих планах не было форматировать диск, но случайно форматировал, лучше со мной не связываться)

на ютубе есть гайд, как это сделать

Но, скажу на будущее - просто поменять кодировку не выйдет, если этот диск являлся системным (C)

просто прикол в том, что у меня нет доступа к файлам которые на диске...

т.е. вы даже диск сам не видите? Странно.. Иначе, берите диск и суйте в другой пк) Мб виртуалка спасёт и вытащит нужные файлы

Оно? https://askubuntu.com/q/762519/457538
